# "Add Delimited Text Layer" plugin is enabled, but does not show up in the plugin menu

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 1.7.1 on Windows 7.  I want to import a delimited text layer, but that option does not appear in the "plugins" menu.  This problem persists, despite the following steps I've taken to remedy it:

1. Disable then Enable "Add Delimited Text Layer" plugin
2. Restart QGIS/Restart computer
3. Uninstall QGIS and GRASS using add/remove programs, then re-install

Is there any way to completely remove all plugins, then re-install and re-enable "Add Delimited Text Layer?"

[image: Plugins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer the add delimited text plugin doesnt add a menu item in the plugins menu, just a button on the Plugins toolbar.

You can go to the View > Toolbars menu and make sure Plugins is checked.